# Magento2 Impact of Setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

I am preparing for certification and I came across one of the questions and I wanted to confirm the options. I know option 4 is correct for sure, confused between 1 and 2. I know setup:upgrade does not clear Magento cache. any help will be appreciated

Question
You have to install a new module on the production environment. All the module is adding a new product attribute. You enabled maintenance mode, copied the module code, run bin/magento setup: upgrade and
disabled maintenance mode.

What two risks does this process pose? (Choose two.)

1. It will clean all caches which will cause performance degradation
2. The new attribute will be invisible on the storefront until the cache is cleaned manually
3. It will void all active sessions
4. It will clean static assets from the pub/static folder

Answer (score 1):

As my experiences, two risks that this process pose are:

1. It will clean all caches which will cause performance degradation
2. It will clean static assets from the pub/static folder

Answer (score 1):

This question was brought into discussion 2 months ago and there were 2 answers:

- One fixed answered for "It will clean all caches which will cause performance degradation"
- The other is either "It will void all active sessions" or "It will clean static assets from the pub/static folder"

See original source: [Association developer certification magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311555/association-developer-certification-magento-2)

Comment: "It will void all active sessions"  is not correct I verified on local and "It will clean static assets from the pub/static folder" is correct. so 1. It will clean all caches which will cause performance degradation 2. It will clean static assets from the pub/static folder should be the correct options. Thank you so much :)